# Align paragraphs in parallel environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, parallel, parallel-texts

I used `\usepackage{parallel}` for typeset into two columns. But two parallel paragraphs do not align correctly. When I insert `\subsubsection` in the first column, the second parallel column has strange empty place (like 1). To regulate horizontal align I use `\vspace{}`, but I understand that it's wrong  solution and for the start parallel doesn't work. The second question Is the possible to create inside vertical rule to separate two columns (like 2)in this package? 
Here source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, top=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{framed}

\voffset = 0pt
\hoffset = 0pt
\headheight = 35pt
\headsep = 0.4cm
\oddsidemargin = -14pt 
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\topskip=0.7cm


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
  \@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum~\@cftasnumb%
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{15}{20}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}\normalsize}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}\normalsize}

\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\begin{document}
\section {My section}
\subsection{My subsection}
\makeatletter\clubpenalty \@clubpenalty\makeatother
 \begin{framed}
\begin{Parallel}{6cm}{10cm}
\ParallelLText{\subsubsection{
My subsubsection + long text
      }}
\ParallelRText{
Long text

}
\ParallelPar
\hrule
\ParallelLText 
{\vspace{10pt}\subsubsection{My subsection}}

\ParallelRText{ \vspace{-100pt}
Long text
}
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}
 \end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Below result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you try to make parallel paragraphs, and one has gignificant structure the other doesn't have, you have to expect problems. I don't know what your `\vspaces` are aiming for so I took them out. Then I added invisible section headings to the right parallel text to match the vissible ones in the left. Finally, I added an invisible paragraph to the second left one to match the paragraph on the right. Things seem to work OK. I've also removed a good deal of your preamble as it didn't seem necessary to exhibit the problem nor the solution.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, top=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{parallel} \usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% so we can see actual "long text"
\voffset = 0pt
\hoffset = 0pt
\headheight = 35pt
\headsep = 0.4cm
\oddsidemargin = -14pt
\parskip = 0pt
\topskip = 0.7cm
\begin{document}
\section {My section}
\subsection{My subsection}

 \begin{framed}
\begin{Parallel}{6cm}{10cm}
\ParallelLText{%
  \subsubsection{My subsubsection}
  \lipsum[1]}
\ParallelRText{%
  \subsubsection*{\mbox{}} % invisible header
  \lipsum[1]}
\ParallelPar
\hrule
\ParallelLText
  {\subsubsection{My subsection}
  \mbox{}}% invisible paragraph
\ParallelRText{%
  \subsubsection*{\mbox{}}% invisible header
  \lipsum[1]}
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}
 \end{framed}
\end{document}
```

I don't know why this works or whether it is the only solution. Personally, I would probably have tried to put the section headings outside the parallel material:

```
\subsection{My subsection}
 \begin{framed}
\subsubsection{My subsubsection}% start parallel after
\begin{Parallel}{6cm}{10cm}
  \ParallelLText{\lipsum[1]}
  \ParallelRText{\lipsum[1]}
  \ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}% end it
\medskip
\hrule
\bigskip
\subsubsection{My subsection}
\begin{Parallel}{6cm}{10cm}% start again
  \ParallelLText{}
  \ParallelRText{\lipsum[1]}
  \ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}
 \end{framed}
```

Comment: Good idea, but It doesn't work for me, because my subsubsection is very long and doesn't fit to my first cell